# Django - dictionary key and value not displaying in template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, web

I'm trying to build a simple blog with Django and am trying to display blog posts and the number of comments on associated with a post. Unfortunately, I'm running into trouble getting my dictionary to print out values--or, at least where I want to.

In my views.h file:

```
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blogs/index.html'
    num_comments = { }

    def get_blogs(self):
        """
        Returns the last 5 published blog posts.
        """
        blogs = BlogPost.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte = timezone.now()    
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

        for blog in blogs:
            # Setting our num_comments dictionary by getting
            # the number of comments from a particular blog post
            self.num_comments[blog.id] = len(Comment.objects.filter(blog_post = blog.id))

        return blogs
```

In my index.html file:

```
{{ view.num_comments }}
{% if view.get_blogs %}
    {% for blog in view.get_blogs %}
        <div>
            <h1>{{ blog.post_title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ blog.post_text }}</p>
            <ul>
                {{ blog.id }}
                {{ view.num_comments }}
                {% for key, value in view.num_comments %}
                <li>
                        {{ key }} <-- Does not display
                        {{ value }} <-- Does not display
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No blogs are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Where I explicitly call `{{ view.num_comments }}`, the correct dictionary is being displayed. Any idea why my dictionary isn't getting the key and value pair correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method to access the key and value pairs:

```
{% for key, value in view.num_comments.items %}
```

Also see the third example in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: Well, that was a dumb oversight. Thank you.